# Do I need to cancel setState operation if data has changed before async operation finished?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

If I use the useState hook to control some data.

```
[data, setData] = useState<any[]>([])
```

Then I kick off an async operation (async 1) that will result in an update to the controlled data.

```
async function deleteByIndex(indexs){
    ...async logic to deleted filtered data from database then update data locally to reflect change
    setData(newData) 
}
```

But prior to async 1 completing the underlying data is modified via some other operation

```
fetchData (){
    setData(getDataFromDatabase())
}
```

So the order is:

```
 deleteByIndex (starts)
 fetchData ( starts + finishes)
 deleteByIndex (finishes)
```

Then I wouldn't want deleteByIndex to update the data as the update is no longer relevant to the new data. So what is the best way to handle scenarios like this where there are race conditions?

Comment: More specifically, to cancel getDataFromDatabase, so it won't reach setState with obsolete data. This problem is one of many reasons why libs that manage side effects exist - Redux Saga, Redux Observable, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is use usePrevious hook to compare new value against old and see if they are the same or not before updating and bailing out if they aren't.